# How to correctly reference and image in the assets folder?

Tags: android, android-assets, simpleadapter

I have some images in my assets folder, and I would like to load them into a ListView by using a SimpleAdapter.

I am referencing the images by their filenames, like: "my_image.jpg".

Here is some code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (String s : imageNames) {
        rows.add(createRow(s));
    }

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this, 
            rows, 
            R.layout.card_list_row, 
            new String[] {"Image"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.list_row_image});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the createRow method:

```
private Map<String, Object> createCardRow(String s) {
    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    row.put("Image", "file:///android_asset/" + s + ".jpg");
    return row;
}
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```
02-12 20:01:22.615: I/System.out(17876): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///android_asset/my_image.jpg
```

And a FileNotFoundException. I obviously know that that image does exist in the assets folder. How can I reference it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)

Using a hardcoded absolute path is never a good practice no matter it works or not.

And there're lots of source examples on web, please google for it.

EDIT:

you see that there's a [`open`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) method in assetManager which returns a `InputStream` for the specified file resource. Then you can use [`decodeStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) to get a `Bitmap` object.

Once you need an image, you can use above steps. As you can find an example easily, I won't show it here.

Comment: I am using a database containing the filenames of the images stored in the assets folder. Do you think there is a better way?

Comment: Database is good at managing a large number of objects or data set that may change (add/delete) often. The management implementation should depend on your requirements. For example, if you only have up to ten images, then there's no need to use a "heavy" database at all.

Comment: I have about 400 objects stored in the database, and each has a reference to an image.

Comment: I think it is ok then.

Comment: So how would I integrate the AssetManager?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try using below function.

```
public void loadDataFromAsset(String imagenamefomdb) {

        try {



            InputStream ims = getAssets().open(imagenamefomdb);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, "image");
            imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
            ims.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return;
        }

    }
```

Hope it works for you